# Friend function defined inside class template. Function template redefinition error

Tags: c++, templates

Below are two code samples. The first one defines `operator+()` for a class template `Vector` while the second one just declares the function but moves the function definition outside the class body. The first sample results in the following error:

```
main.cpp(4): error C2995:
'Vector<L,T> operator +(const Vector<L,T> &,const Vector<L,T> &)' :
function template has already been defined
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why do the two template instantiations in main() result in function template redefinition errors? Based on my understanding, they should result in unique instances as the template parameters are different.
2. How does moving the function definition outside of the class body resolve the error?

Error sample:

```
template<int L, typename T>
class Vector {

  template<int L, typename T> friend
  Vector<L, T> operator+(const Vector<L, T>& lhs, const Vector<L, T>& rhs) {
    return Vector<L, T>();
  }

private:
  T data[L];
};

int main() {
  Vector<42, double> v42d;
  Vector<24, int> v24i;

  return 0;
}
```

Working sample:

```
template<int L, typename T>
class Vector {

  template<int L, typename T> friend
  Vector<L, T> operator+(const Vector<L, T>& lhs, const Vector<L, T>& rhs);

private:
  T data[L];
};

template<int L, typename T>
Vector<L, T> operator+(const Vector<L, T>& lhs, const Vector<L, T>& rhs) {
  return Vector<L, T>();
}

int main() {
  Vector<42, double> v42d;
  Vector<24, int> v24i;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shadow template parameters in both samples. Is this your real code?

Comment: BTW, with shadow fixed, clang accepts code and g++ rejects it [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0046cac7d6f39125).

Comment: @Jarod42 The error is the same on MSVC2013 as long as both the parameters template variables and the return type's template variables are specified explicitly.

Comment: @Columbo Yes. It is an example based on my actual code which shadows the parameters as well, and cost me 4 hours to find the root cause :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template types L and T are already known, so don't need to be reintroduced. In fact doing so for the friend function causes them to overshadow the ones defined for the class.

this fixes it:

```
template<int L, typename T>
class Vector {

    friend
    Vector<L, T> operator+(const Vector<L, T>& lhs, const Vector<L, T>& rhs) {
        return Vector<L, T>();
    }

private:
    T data[L];
};
```

which is equivalent to:

```
template<int L, typename T>
class Vector {

    friend
    Vector operator+(const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs) {
        return Vector();
    }

private:
    T data[L];
};
```

Comment: You may even omit `<L, T>`.